# Cast DateTime column value in to DD MM YYYY hh:mm:ss:SSS format in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to convert to current datetime format into "DD MM YYYY hh:mm:ss:SSS", is there any logic that I need to write or any predefined variable exist in SQL.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? You should explain your problem in more detail because you're probably making a mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below mentioned code

```
select CONVERT(VARCHAR(24),GETDATE(),113)
```

and for more format look into [SQL Code](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You would probably want to use `format`.

```
select format(getdate(), 'dd MM yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff');
```

Which produces this:

```
18 06 2016 09:42:33.320
```

Hope this helps.